# Unique Like Buttons in Fancybox Gallery

Tags: php, javascript, fancybox, facebook-like, expressionengine

I have googled hither and thither but have yet to find a clear answer about this issue. [This question helped me the most](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243163/like-action-not-showing-on-users-wall), but I am still having trouble getting Like buttons to post an image to a user's timeline.

On several pages of my site, example.com/gallery/my-gallery, there are 10 photos. I'm using [Fancybox](http://fancyapps.com) as an image viewer. My intention is for a Like button on each slide to allow the user to Like the image and for that activity to be recorded on their Timeline.

Using encoded URLs with a unique query, I can get the activity to record on a timeline, but the problem is that the image does not show up unless I Lint the custom Url first using FB's debugger.

I'm using the iFrame Like button and grabbing a unique image URL like so:

```js
// Inside my call to Fancybox, I am using two event listeners
beforeLoad : function(){
    var that = this

    // this/that is the absolute url to the image.
    // I split it off into a variable img that I will use as a query string.
    a = function(){
        var url = that.href
        var img = url.split("http://example.com").pop()
        return img
    }
},
afterLoad : function(e){
    // argument "e" lets me dig in and the current Gallery URL 'example.com/gallery/my-gallery' 
    var galUrl = e.parent.context.URL
    // now I have pathToImg that I can use as a query string
    var pathToImg = a()
```

Ok now I use a combination of `galUrl` and `pathToImg` to build a unique url:

```js
var thisURL = encodeURIComponent(galUrl + '?' + pathToImg)

// still in afterLoad() at this point, so I dynamically create a Like button with the proper parameters
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=' + thisURL + '&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=50&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font=segoe+ui&amp;height=21&amp;appId=########" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:80px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

FWIW, the appID parameter (`########`) is linked to an "app" on FB's developer dashboard. The app domain is set to example.com, and under Integrates with Facebook, I have chose "Website with Facebook Login" and the site URL is http://example.com (note the addition of the protocol). I have made no other configuration changes. Sandbox mode is off.

Ok, the last bit is modifying the OG tags on the referring url (what `thisURL` resolves to). As you may or may not know, FB will send its OG parser to the url supplied in the href parameter, which looks something like http://example.com/gallery/my-gallery?/path/to/image.jpg (but it's actually URL encoded). I'm using PHP in my meta tags to supply pick up the query string and show FB what I want it to see.

```php
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:image" content="<?= "http://example.com".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; ?>" />
<meta property="og:url" content="<?= "http://example.com".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" />
```

Given a URL like `http://example.com/gallery/my-gallery?/path/to/image.jpg`, the `og:image` tag resolves to `http://example.com/path/to/image.jpg` and the `og:url` tag resolves to `http://example.com/gallery/my-gallery?/path/to/image.jpg`.

This is on a CMS (ExpressionEngine), so that block is actually wrapped in a conditional.

My other meta tags:

```php
<meta property="og:title" content="WEBSITE TITLE - {embed="includes/page-title segment='{segment_1}'"}" />      
<meta property="og:description" content="WEBSITE DESCRIPTION">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="WEBSITE NAME" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="#########" />
```

Now when I like a photo, I see it in my recent activity on my Facebook profile with all the expected OG tags, **EXCEPT FOR THE IMAGE.** When I use FB's Debugger to inspect http://example.com/gallery/my-gallery?/path/to/image.jpg, I get all of the expected values, **INCLUDING THE IMAGE**.

If I lint that url first, and then Like the image, the image **does** appear on my timeline. I don't know that programmatically linting every query-stringed url is an option.

Nearly at my wits end. Can someone help?

Comment: You might have to put an iframe in the lightbox, instead of the img.  So, you;d have an iframe with all the correct og stuff and the page would be nothing but the picture.  Lots of lightboxes will let you popup an iframe instead of just the img.  I remember seeing a post about that for http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/ which is th e lightbox i use.  I cant find it, atm. If you get it going, i'd love to see.  myfirstname@firstlast.com